# SuspiciousOperation :Attempted access to path default_storage django

Tags: python, django, mod-python, django-storage, django-errors

I'm trying to save a `PDF` into a folder in my `project` the `folder` has the permissions `read, write` when I try to save the `PDF` I get this error:

> SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to /opt/django_apps/inscripcion/solicitudes/filename

and this is my simple code:

```
 contenido = "Simple code"
 file_name = "/opt/django_apps/inscripcion/solicitudes/filename"
 path = default_storage.save(file_name, ContentFile(contenido))
```

I'm using `python2.7` with `mod_python` and `django1.3` on `RedHat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual exception is raised in `django/utils/_os.py` on line 76:

```
raise ValueError('The joined path (%s) is located outside of the base '
                 'path component (%s)' % (final_path, base_path))
```

And `base_path` for `default_storage` is `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`.

I'd suggest creating `FileSystemStorage` with

```
file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location = '/opt/django_apps/inscripcion/solicitudes/')
```

And then

```
contenido = "Simple code"
file_name = "filename"
path = file_storage.save(file_name, ContentFile(contenido))
```

Comment: I'll try after now I've fixed with the `built-in` `open` function :D

Comment: well, the simplest decision beats all:)